# Is there a way to calculate alerts in table view?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have a tableview which has events and the user can select yes, no, maybe options from `alert controller`. I like to calculate number of yes, no, maybe. I could have used `UISwitch` and calculated it, if there is yes and no option like this and storing the value in `eventStatus`

```
 eventSwitch.isOn = object.value(forKey: "eventStatus") as! Bool
```

Is there a way, I can do the same with alert controller, which has yes, no,maybe (3 options)?

Comment: How about implementing the calculations in alert actions?

Comment: Yeah that is what I am not able to figure out, I searched everywhere for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to implement those calculations in alert action handlers:

```
var yesCount = 0
var noCount = 0
var maybeCount = 0
func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "yes", style: .default) { _ in
        self.yesCount += 1
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .default) { _ in
        self.noCount += 1
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "maybe", style: .default) { _ in
        self.maybeCount += 1
    })
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it, got the idea now.